# Problem trying to increase the size of the BootCamp disk

Tags: mac, partitioning, boot-camp

I'm trying to increase the size of the BootCamp disk on my imac.
I had 32 Go (in FAT32) before. I deleted the partition. 
Now I try to use something bigger (80 or 90 Gb) but Boot Camp tells
me that "the disk cannnot be partitionned besause it's impossible to move some of its files".
Strange, I have enough free space (200Gb). Thanks for your advices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Note that if Boot Camp says it cannot move files, you'll have to use a 3rd party disk defragmenter like Disk Tools Pro to defragment your disk, and then try this step again."](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20061025130528687)